# Cannot use Android Crop image crop library in Android

Tags: android, image, crop, resize-crop, android-crop

I am developing an Android project. In my project, I want to add crop image feature. So I used this library, https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop. But when I use it. It is giving me error.

**This is how I installed:**

1. I put this in grandle, compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
2. I put this in manifest file,

**This is how I am using in code:**

1. I open Image picker like this

   `Crop.pickImage(CurrentActivity.this, IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_COODE);`
2. In onActivityResult, I am doing like this

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if(requestCode==IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_COODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
       {
           Crop.of(data.getData(),null).asSquare().start(CreateItemActivity.this);
       }
       else if(requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
       {
           Uri filePath = data.getData();
       }
   }
   ```
3. But after I crop the image and I click "OK", the result of the activity is not equal to OK. So I cannot retrieve cropped image data.

   So I removed `resultCode==RESULT_OK` and I retrieved like this:

   ```
    if(requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP)
    {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
    }
   ```

Data is always null. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `build.gradle` file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
}
```

Make the layout of Image like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/content_padding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
            android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/butterfly"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fixedAspectRatioLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fixedAspectRatio"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:text="@string/fixedAspectRatio"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/fixedAspectRatioToggle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"/>

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding_half"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aspectRatioXHeader"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/aspectRatioXHeader"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aspectRatioX"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                tools:text="10"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/aspectRatioXSeek"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="10"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding_half"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aspectRatioYHeader"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/aspectRatioYHeader"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aspectRatioY"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                tools:text="10"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/aspectRatioYSeek"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="10"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/showGuidelinesLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding_half"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/showGuidelines"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/showGuidelines"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/showGuidelinesSpin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:entries="@array/showGuidelinesArray"
                    android:gravity="start"/>

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_crop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding"
            android:minWidth="120dp"
            android:text="@string/crop"
            android:textColor="#33B5E5"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/croppedImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/croppedImageDesc"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int GUIDELINES_ON_TOUCH = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Views.
        final ToggleButton fixedAspectRatioToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.fixedAspectRatioToggle);
        final TextView aspectRatioXTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aspectRatioX);
        final SeekBar aspectRatioXSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.aspectRatioXSeek);
        final TextView aspectRatioYTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aspectRatioY);
        final SeekBar aspectRatioYSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.aspectRatioYSeek);
        final Spinner guidelinesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.showGuidelinesSpin);
        final CropImageView cropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
        final ImageView croppedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.croppedImageView);
        final Button cropButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_crop);

        // Initializes fixedAspectRatio toggle button.
        fixedAspectRatioToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                cropImageView.setFixedAspectRatio(isChecked);
                cropImageView.setAspectRatio(aspectRatioXSeekBar.getProgress(), aspectRatioYSeekBar.getProgress());
                aspectRatioXSeekBar.setEnabled(isChecked);
                aspectRatioYSeekBar.setEnabled(isChecked);
            }
        });
        // Set seek bars to be disabled until toggle button is checked.
        aspectRatioXSeekBar.setEnabled(false);
        aspectRatioYSeekBar.setEnabled(false);

        aspectRatioXTextView.setText(String.valueOf(aspectRatioXSeekBar.getProgress()));
        aspectRatioYTextView.setText(String.valueOf(aspectRatioXSeekBar.getProgress()));

        // Initialize aspect ratio X SeekBar.
        aspectRatioXSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar aspectRatioXSeekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (progress < 1) {
                    aspectRatioXSeekBar.setProgress(1);
                }
                cropImageView.setAspectRatio(aspectRatioXSeekBar.getProgress(), aspectRatioYSeekBar.getProgress());
                aspectRatioXTextView.setText(String.valueOf(aspectRatioXSeekBar.getProgress()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do nothing.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        });

        // Initialize aspect ratio Y SeekBar.
        aspectRatioYSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar aspectRatioYSeekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (progress < 1) {
                    aspectRatioYSeekBar.setProgress(1);
                }
                cropImageView.setAspectRatio(aspectRatioXSeekBar.getProgress(), aspectRatioYSeekBar.getProgress());
                aspectRatioYTextView.setText(String.valueOf(aspectRatioYSeekBar.getProgress()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do nothing.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        });

        // Set up the Guidelines Spinner.
        guidelinesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                cropImageView.setGuidelines(i);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        });
        guidelinesSpinner.setSelection(GUIDELINES_ON_TOUCH);

        // Initialize the Crop button.
        cropButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Bitmap croppedImage = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
                croppedImageView.setImageBitmap(croppedImage);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

for more detail visit this : https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Comment: @Wai Yan Hein see my answer below.

Comment: Yes. But for that one, I need to upgrade sdk, libraries and so on. I have low internet connection and data is expensive in my current location. That is why I use this one. So this library is not working?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That library is useful. So can you edit answer mentioning that library? So I can upvote the answer.

Comment: @WaiYanHein glad to help you.